# What is a secure way to prevent a user from updating specific fields in a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to prevent users from updating certain fields in a mongodb object for which they are allowed to edit every other field. For instance the user should be able to edit/add/remove all fields except the field "permissions". My current approach is to test each key the user is trying to "$set" and see if it starts with the substring "permissions" (to cover dot notation). Example in python:

```
def sanitize_set(son):
    return {"$set": {k: v for k, v in son.get("$set", {}).items()
            if not k.startswith("permissions")}}
```

This approach is beautifully simple and seems to work. I wanted to reach out to the community to see if anyone else has tackled this issue before or sees obvious flaws in my approach. Thank you,

Joshua

Comment: Is there a distinct set of fields which every user is allowed to edit? If you could show a sample document, that might make your proposal clearer.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that the user can edit the document in any way they want except for certain fields I want protected. An example document would be: {"name": "test_object", "permissions": {"Joshua": ["AttributeA", "AttributeB"], "John": ["AttributeA"]}}. In this example a user could edit the name, delete the field name, add a field "phone", or generally anything they want to except edit the permissions field.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing some example data with an explanation of what should/shouldn't be updatable - it's hard to say for sure, but the way I would prevent this would be to **not** allow the user to directly supply the fields they will be updating.  For example say you had a function called `update_employee` which updated information in an employee document.  If you implement it like this:

```
update_employee(employee):
   db.employees.update({_id: session.user_id}, {$set: employee})
```

Whatever gets passed in as the `employee` object is what will be updated.  Instead you could create the update object using the values passed in like so:

```
update_employee(employee):
   updatedEmployee = {
      email: employee.email,
      address: employee.address,
      phone: employee.phone
   }
   db.employees.update({_id: session.user_id}, {$set: updatedEmployee})
```

This way you have complete control over what is being updated in your database.  So if an extra field (such as `salary`) is passed in, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since (as far as I know) does not have a field lock, what you can do in this case is create a routine to pick up the specific document, present it to the user in any way you wish, but simply only show the fields they are allowed to edit.
2. You can present the entire JSON representation to the user (editor) and have a routine which simply does not allow changes to the fields that are locked. In other words if you dont want field `{"name": "Sam"}` to be edited even if the editor changes this value to `{"name": "Joe"}` just kick it out before updating and only update fields which are allowed to be edited. Since it is all done in memory before an actual update (upsert) you have total control over what is being edited and what is not.
3. If you follow a scheme which does have a prefix say e_address where you have decided any field with e_ allows editing, the job is that much easier programmatically.
4. Even in user-defined roles I have not seen any possibility of locking specific fields in a collection. (I could be wrong here.)
5. The programming constructs here are simple though.
   A. Pick up field to memory
   B. Editor does editing
   C. Only update fields which are allowed to be edited. Any other changes just ignore.

(I kept this answer generic as I do not use Python, though the construct should apply to any language.)

Comment: I know MongoDB is susceptible to Null Byte Injection Attack in the key string (https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/02/mongodb-null-byte-injection-attacks/). By comparing the start of the string to a substring I think I am protecting myself against this attack. Do your examples protect against this particular attack?

Comment: @Joshua even in the article you quoted at the end it says: "The best solution is to strictly validate the fields you allow users to pass to a collection, additionally check each user-supplied database and collection string for the presence of null-bytes." If you look at what I wrote in my answer, do everything in memory. After that check each field  you need to check with a function for allowed edits and null bytes (and any other verification you need.) Forcing updates in memory do not allow direct contact with the collection, until the code verifies it.